# JSON and D3, Change only children key names but leave parent

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

In order to make my D3 graphs work correctly, I need the children's names to not be "key" but "label". The parents still need to be "key".

Here is my code and the output. Below that is a couple things I've tried, without success.

Stretch goal, if possible: I don't necessarily want to "hardcode" it either. I'd like to be able to change any level (just the first level in this case) of children's names to whatever I want ("label" in this case).

```js
var csv = `breakfastItem,gluten,breakfastItemType,month,year,dateCode,value
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,May,2017,42856,300
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,March,2017,42795,100
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,November,2016,42675,20
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,February,2017,42767,50
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,November,2016,42675,30
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,March,2016,42430,100
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2018,43132,200
Bagel,Yes,Plain,December,2017,43070,202
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2016,42401,201`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  d.year = +d.year;
  d.dateCode = +d.dateCode;
  return d;
});

var breakfastCombinations = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.breakfastItem;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.breakfastItemType;
  })
  .rollup(function(oldestDate) {
    return oldestDate.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.dateCode - a.dateCode
    })[0].value
  })
  .entries(data);

console.log(breakfastCombinations)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Example from [here](http://learnjsdata.com/group_data.html) is the first thing I looked at.

```
var expenseMetrics = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return {
    count: v.length,
    total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.amount; }),
    avg: d3.mean(v, function(d) { return d.amount; })
}; })
```

This second example is something I believe could work, but I'm not sure how to access the children and not just the parent.

```
breakfastCombinations.forEach(function(d) {
  d.label = d.key;
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [d3.map](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Arrays.md#d3_map) to map the items:

For example, if you're looking for parent mapping from "key" to "label", use the following:

```
.entries(data).map(function(group) {
  // parent mapping
  return {label: group.key, values: group.values};
})
```

```js
var csv = `breakfastItem,gluten,breakfastItemType,month,year,dateCode,value
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,May,2017,42856,300
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,March,2017,42795,100
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,November,2016,42675,20
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,February,2017,42767,50
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,November,2016,42675,30
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,March,2016,42430,100
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2018,43132,200
Bagel,Yes,Plain,December,2017,43070,202
Bdagel,Yes,Plain,December,2017,43070,202
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2016,42401,201`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  d.year = +d.year;
  d.dateCode = +d.dateCode;
  return d;
});

var breakfastCombinations = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.breakfastItem;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.breakfastItemType;
  })
  .rollup(function(oldestDate) {
    return oldestDate.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.dateCode - a.dateCode
    })[0].value
  })
  .entries(data).map(function(group) {
  // parent mapping
    return {label: group.key, values: group.values};
  })

console.log(breakfastCombinations);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

And if you're looking for children mapping, use something like this:

```
.entries(data).map(function(group) {
    // children mapping
    return {key: group.key, values: group.values.map(function(d) { return {label: d.key, value: d.value}})};
})
```

```js
var csv = `breakfastItem,gluten,breakfastItemType,month,year,dateCode,value
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,May,2017,42856,300
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,March,2017,42795,100
Bagel,Yes,Cinnamon Raisin,November,2016,42675,20
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,February,2017,42767,50
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,November,2016,42675,30
Bagel,Yes,Blueberry,March,2016,42430,100
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2018,43132,200
Bagel,Yes,Plain,December,2017,43070,202
Bdagel,Yes,Plain,December,2017,43070,202
Bagel,Yes,Plain,February,2016,42401,201`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  d.year = +d.year;
  d.dateCode = +d.dateCode;
  return d;
});

var breakfastCombinations = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.breakfastItem;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.breakfastItemType;
  })
  .rollup(function(oldestDate) {
    return oldestDate.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.dateCode - a.dateCode
    })[0].value
  })
  .entries(data).map(function(group) {
  // children mapping
    return {key: group.key, values: group.values.map(function(d) { return {label: d.key, value: d.value}})};
  })

console.log(breakfastCombinations);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Basically, you can use manipulate the array using d3.map as per the requirements.

Hope this helps.